# Vegas Pro to Movie Maker.

Tags: conversion, windows-movie-maker, sony-vegas

I make a project about a video in Vegas Pro 11 and I want to continue my progress in Windows Movie Maker, because I'm on vacations and my PC here has no Vegas Pro on it. Can I convert Sony Vegas Pro (.veg) files to Movie Maker files (.mswmm)? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely no as there is a severe difference in capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

No, this really isn't possible.

As Seth mentioned, the technical differences between what Vegas Pro can do and Windows Movie Maker can do are astronomical. Even between similarly capable programs, like Vegas and Premiere Pro, the project files from one cannot be opened in another.

You could certainly render what you have from Vegas, load the render into Movie Maker, and import the remaining clips to Movie Maker, but this would likely create an unwanted dip in quality.